# Adicionar ao select e exibir na tela

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um select:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="dataInstalacao">
<option value="0/0" selected disabled>Quando podemos instalar?</option>
<option value="6/9">6/9</option>
<option value="7/9">7/9</option>
<option value="8/9">8/9</option>
<option value="9/9">9/9</option>                                                     
</select>
```

Eu uso o seguinte código para adicionar mais options :

```
var newOption = new Option("teste", data.id, false, false);
$('#dataInstalacao').append(newOption).trigger('change');
```

O que acontece é que o quando inspeciono o elemento, o novo option está lá, mas o que é exibido na tela é uma lista `UL>LI` e o select tem `display:none`e essa lista não contem o novo item.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como devo prosseguir?

Comment: Não seria mais simples fazer assim? `$('#dataInstalacao').append(new Option('Foo', 'foo', true, true));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pela classe do `<ul>` dá pra ver que tu está usando uma biblioteca para alterar os selects nativos. Pelo que vi é o [Nice Select](http://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/).

Segundo a [documentação](http://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/) basta chamar a função `update` para que o plugin atualize a `<ul>`.

Então teu código ficaria algo assim:

```js
var newOption = new Option("teste", data.id, false, false);
$('#dataInstalacao').append(newOption).niceSelect('update');
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, valeu!!!!

Comment: Se a resposta ajudou marque como correta para que futuros visitantes saibam que funcionou.

Comment: Eu não tinha marcado ainda porque não deu o tempo kkkkk